# Remove duplicate events in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a FullCalendar where I generated a whole week with events.
From the database I got all events which are blocked.
The blocked events could be same length or longer.
My problem is, after hours of trying, that I either delete the wrong events or no events.
My biggest problem is to compare the 2 events.
I work with moment.js and moment-range.js.

The goal is that the blocked events are not even more in the calendar and the time from the blocked event are empty.
I posted my code on http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/onipancb.

If you have any question feel free to ask.

Many thanks in advance.

Initialization

```
events = [];

var myCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    minTime: "08:00:00",
    maxTime: "19:00:00",
    firstDay: moment().format('e'),
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    weekends: false,


  });
```

Fill Calendar with generated events

```
function fillCalendarWithEvents() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSources', events);
    var currentDate = moment.now();
    var beginOfWeek = currentDate.start;
    var endOfWeek = currentDate.end;
    var startDay = moment(beginOfWeek).set({
      'hour': 8,
      'minute': 0
    });

    var minutesOfBlock = 30;


    for (var day = 0; day < 14; day++) {

      for (var blocks = 0; blocks < 24; blocks++) {

        var startEvent = startDay.format();
        var endEvent = startDay.add(minutesOfBlock, 'm').format();

        if (isEventNotInPast(startEvent)) {

          events.push({
            title: 'Freier Termin',
            start: startEvent,
            end: endEvent,
            backgroundColor: '#66cdaa',
            url: ""
          });

        }

      }
      startDay.add(1, 'd').set({
        'hour': 8,
        'minute': 0
      });
    }
  }
```

Remove events if they are same like blockedEvents

```
  function removeBlockEvents(){
    for(var all = 0; all < events.length; all++){
      for(var blocked = 0; blocked < blockedEventsJSON.length; blocked++){
      const  range = moment.range(events[all].start, events[all].end);
        start = moment(blockedEventsJSON[blocked].begin);
        if(range.contains(start)){
          events.splice(all, 1);


        }
      }
    }
  }



$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
```

Example Data from blockedEvents

```
blockedEventsJSON = JSON.parse('[{"id":55,"status":0,"user":2,"begin":"2017-06-20 09:00:00","end":"2017-06-20 09:30:00","gcalenderstatus":0,"title":null,"description":"Termin von ","created_at":"2017-06-16 20:24:20","updated_at":"2017-06-16 20:24:20"}]')
```

[In this picture is the calendar. The event which is
contemporaneous with a blocked event should be not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo9rq.png)

Comment: please post the _relevant_ code here so people can easily see it (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But anyway your statements "From the database i got all events which are blocked" and "The goal is that the blocked events are not even more in the calendar". These sound like contradictions. If you don't want your "blocked" events in the calendar, why are you returning them from the database? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please look at the link. There you can see the problem and also the quellcode. The goal is an empty space where a blocked event was.

Comment: As I said, please post the relevant code here so people can easily see it (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I am not going to read your whole source code to find the relevant part. Also, links to off-site resources can go stale for future readers. And you haven't answered my question about what you are actually trying to do. If you don't want to show "blocked" events (whatever that means?), then don't include them in your event feed.

Comment: There was only the relevant part but anyways i posted the code at this post :)

For a whole week i generate all events from the code. Than i have the blocked events and where a blocked event is there should be a empty place. So a client cant store at the same event.

Comment: Ok I see better now. It would a lot easier if you just showed the "blocked" events, and don't bother with generating the "free" events - free slots should be shown as simply empty space on the grid, so that users can select the area to add an event. You can use other rules to make sure they only select blocks of time in pre-determined sizes, if necessary. I think this is making a lot of effort to do something unnecessary. IMO you are creating a problem you don't need to have.